# Deleting NULL results

Tags: sql-server, null

Currently I'm just trying to delete objects with the Name column being Null from a temp table with the following...

```
delete from #PulledData
where #PulledData.Name0 = NULL
```

I've also tried `= 'NULL'`, `= '%NULL%'` etc. but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate some help on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete from #PulledData where #PulledData.Name0 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `IS NULL`.

This could be fixed another way to use the `=` syntax, but that option is [going away soon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).